# Can android phone block communication with server?

Tags: python, android-studio, socket.io, aiohttp

I wrote client in android studio and server in python(socketIO aiohttp)
when I run the program in android studio(in the virtual machine) it works perfectly

But when I test the program on my phone(LG V10) the client doesn't manage to connect to the server and there is no exception

any ideas?

Comment: setup logging on your server to make sure if it really doesn't connect to the server. also checkout `adb logcat` for more verbosity.

Comment: @Juggernaut yeah I did all of that, the phone still doesn't connect to the server